# Run-time error in destructor delete. c++

Tags: c++, oop

i try to implement a Queue(Data structue).
I have some problem when i make a d'tor include a delete,only if i delete the function "delete *char" ,it`s work and it's look very odd for me.
this my code:
Node.h

```
class Node
    {
        public:
            Node();
            Node(char*,int);

            ~Node();
            Node(const Node& t);//copy c`tor
            Node& operator= (const Node&);
    .....

        private:
            char * name;
            int money;
     .....
    };
```

Node.cpp:

```
Node::Node() //c`tor
{}
Node::~Node() //d`tor
{
    //delete [] name;

}
Node::Node(char * n,int m){ //c`tor
    name = new char[strlen(n)+1];
    strcpy(name,n);
    money = m;
}
Node::Node(const Node& t){ //copy c`tor
    name = new char[strlen(t.name)+1];
    strcpy(name,t.name);
    money = t.money;
}
Node& Node::operator= (const Node& t){
    if(this != &t){
    name = new char[strlen(t.name)+1];//EDITED
    strcpy(name,t.name);
}
return *this;
```

}

the main.cpp

```
int main()
{

    Node k1("Naor",100),k2("Klock",200);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT 1:
i fix the allocate at operator=,and the error not connect to Queue class so i delete they also,still run-time error.

Comment: please provide a [mcve] and dont forget to ask a question

Comment: why are you not using `std::string` ?

Comment: Use std::string!

Comment: Your default `Node` constructor leaves the `name` member uninitialized.  Hence calling `delete [] name` in that case will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: cant use std::string,it's a execrise from college....

Comment: YAIT (yet another incompetent teacher). Then implement yout own string class and use it.

Comment: in that case you should write a class that encapsulates a `char*` and provides an interface similar to `std::string`. It is a shame that teachers still think that they must force their students to write extremely bad code....

Comment: Chances are somewhere in your code you are modifying the value of `name` so that it doesn't point at the original address. Calling `delete[]` on a changed pointer causes undefined behavior. Impossible to tell without a MCVE.

Comment: _"I have some problem"_ What problem? A run-time error? Why did you not, then, quote that error in full for readers?

Comment: @underscore_d i`ts not drop any error at visual studio

Comment: I Fix the code ,look at EDIT 1

Comment: You should mark the answer as accepted, then.

Comment: still run time error

Comment: The posted code compiles and run fine, now, even uncommenting the delete statement in destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't implement the `operator=()` that means it generated by compiler. So, in this case the `Node` will be simply copied, and you'll have a **double free** on `delete[] name` call.

**UPDATE**

In addition to said above this code as an undefined behavior because you `strcpy()` to not allocated memory since the default constructor doesn't allocate it.

```
Node& Node::operator= (const Node& t){
    if(this != &t){
    strcpy(name,t.name);
}
```

Comment: I implement ,sorry i delete it from the exmple for short reading.Edit now

Comment: @NaorMalca see the update.

Comment: @NaorMalca You'de be better posting Queue class as well, at least the addNode method.

Comment: I fix the allocate but still error.

Comment: also i edit the code without the Queue class